# Angular new router how to define a default route when no mapped route

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

I'm using [angular new router](https://github.com/angular/router) and configured it as following:

```
this.$router.config([
                {path: '/', component: 'home', as:'home'},
                {path: '/home', component: 'home'},
                {path: '/home/:type/:id', component: 'home'}
            ]);
```

How can I define a default route when the URL isn't mapped in the list?
I'm searching for something similar to "otherwise" option for a default route.

e.g. when user send /home/group I want it to be mapped to default component, currently I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot read property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined

Comment: You do know that that repo is out of date and not maintained?

Comment: @vascowhite I know but the new router probably will be published in the next angular version and I'm preparing for it like many others in the community